# How to pass model int property and model array int property to jQuery and vice versa in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been stuck on this one for the past 4 days.

[DenominationModel.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjvCm.png)

[View Image JS function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdngY.png)

```
public class DenominationModel
{
    public int DenomValue { get; set; }
    public int[] DenomSlips { get; set; }
}    


<script type="text/javascript">
function DataTest() {
    var DenomValue = '@Model.DenomValue';
    var DenomSlips = [];
    DenomSlips = '@Model.DenomSlips';

    DenomValue = 15;
    DenomSlips[0] = 5;
    DenomSlips[1] = 10;
    @Model.DenomSlips=DenomSlips;
    @Model.DenomValue=DenomValue;
}
```

In the above screenshots and the code, after the button click, I want to assign the `DataTest` function model property to the jQuery var `DenomValue` from Model -> DenomValue.

My model `DenomValue` has value 10, but it is not assigned to the jQuery variable. The same operation needed to be done for the array also and I changed the `DenomValue` data and `DenomSlips` array data and I need to pass it to the model values accordingly.

I have been stuck with this for the past 4 days - please help me as soon as possible. I completed the Buttonclick function in the view if I click the button DataTest function is triggered I checked with console.log it is working fine. Please I want to be fixed by today please

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add the C# and jQuery code as **properly formatted text** - not as screenshots....

Comment: Hi @marc_s I have added code please check and help me I will also find a solution

Answer (score 0):

You need `Html.Raw()` and JSON serializer to serialize the JSON into string and convert it into a plain markup.

Define the import `@using` at the top of the page:

```
@using System.Text.Json;
```

In your JS script:

```js
var DenomValue = @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.DenomValue));
var DenomSlips = @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.DenomSlips));
```

Also, it is inappropriate to assign the value to the `Model` in the JavaScript function.

Unsure why are you doing this, but if you want to submit the model values to API, you should need an input element to set the value.

```
<form> <!-- Specify method, action in form element -->
  <input type="hidden" name="DenomValue" id="txtDenomValue" />
  <input type="hidden" name="DenomSlips[]" id="txtDenomSlips" />
</form>
```

```
function DataTest() {
    var DenomValue = @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.DenomValue));
    var DenomSlips = @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.DenomSlips));

    DenomValue = 15;
    DenomSlips[0] = 5;
    DenomSlips[1] = 10;

    document.getElementById("DenomSlips").value = DenomSlips;
    document.getElementById("DenomValue").value = DenomValue;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yong Shun thank you for the help and in the document.getElementById I need to pass txtDenomValue and txtDenomSlips right instead of Denomslips and Denomvalue

Comment: Yes, it is not possible to assign the value in JS to the `Model`. And you need the text fields to store the value, so when you want to pass those modified values in JS to API controller, you need to submit the form which contains both text fields.